# WooCommerce Add To Cart Button text change using jQuery if Quantity increase

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce Add To Cart Button text change using jQuery if Quantity increase.

```
    jQuery(document).on("change",'.minus', function() { 
  var productquantity = jQuery('.qty').attr('value');
    if  (productquantity == 15) {
          jQuery('.single-product').each(function() {
        jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").text("REQUEST A QUOTE");
    });
      }
})
```

While selecting buttons value never changes :S

HTML FOR BUTTON AND SELECTOR

```
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="minus button is-form"><input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="9999" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"><input type="button" value="+" class="plus button is-form"></div>

<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="1520" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" style="display: block !important">Add to Cart</button>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qg09qe9/)

Comment: show the button html is it Input type or a Link

Comment: @Kashyap updated.

Comment: use this Instead

Comment: Try this - I am updated Your fiddle --https://jsfiddle.net/8qg09qe9/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('body').on("click",'.minus',function ()
  {
      var qtyval = $('.qty').val();
      if(qtyval >= 0)
      {
        var newQTY = parseInt(qtyval) - parseInt(1);
        if(newQTY >= 15)
        {
         $('.single_add_to_cart_button').text("Request a Quote");
        }
        if(newQTY < 15)
        {
         $('.single_add_to_cart_button').text("Add to Cart");
        }
        $('.qty').val(newQTY);
      }
       
  });
  
   $('body').on("click",'.plus',function ()
   {
      var qtyval = $('.qty').val();
      var newQTY = parseInt(qtyval) + parseInt(1);
      if(newQTY >= 15)
      {
       $('.single_add_to_cart_button').text("Request a Quote");
      }
      $('.qty').val(newQTY);
   });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="minus button is-form"><input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="9999" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" 

class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric"><input type="button" value="+" class="plus button is-form"></div>

<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="1520" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" style="display: block !important">Add to Cart</button>
```

Comment: It jumps from 13 to 15 and then 15 to 17. 14 and 16 is missing. Well I resolved this issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).on("click",'.plus, .minus', function() { 
  var productquantity = jQuery('.qty').attr('value');
    if  (productquantity == 15) {
          jQuery('.single-product').each(function() {
        jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").text("REQUEST A QUOTE");
    });
      }  else if(productquantity != 15) {
          jQuery('.single-product').each(function() {
        jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").text("ADD TO CART NOW");
    });
      }
})
```

Only problem was on change to onclick.