# Woocommerce - display different add to cart button if quantity change

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I searched all Internet, but I can't find it. I have two buttons in my Woo store, one is Add to cart and second is Request a quote. What i want to achieve is:

when quantity is =< 5 - display add to cart 
when quantity is > 5 - display request a quote

I tried to use multiple "solutions" from the Internet but nothing works as i want. I have something like this, but i need help. I saw this solution but for my needs I want to display it in php if it's possible:

[WooCommerce Add To Cart Button text change using jQuery if Quantity increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033017/woocommerce-add-to-cart-button-text-change-using-jquery-if-quantity-increase)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with php, if the quantity can be edited in the cart. To use php, the data has to be stored before, but you need the button the change the text on time. So you will have to use javascript for this. Please give us a little bit of code what you have tried so far and what problems you experienced with this solutions. Thank you

Comment: My sample code is here: 'jQuery(document).on("click",'.plus, .minus', function() { 
  var productquantity = jQuery('.quantity').attr('value');
    if  (productquantity == 15) {
          jQuery('.single-product').each(function() {
        jQuery(".add_to_cart_button").text("REQUEST A QUOTE");
    });
      }  else if(productquantity != 15) {
          jQuery('.single-product').each(function() {
        jQuery(".add_to_cart_button").text("ADD TO CART");
    });
      }
})'

Comment: You can edit your question and put your code there, so it is more readable. Please put it inside a code block. Thank you very much.